# Apache VHost Configuration Precedence?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, httpd, virtualhost

So I have 2 configuration files.

mysite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias     mysite.com *.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/mysite/www
        ErrorDocument 404 /redirect.php
    ErrorLog    logs/application/mysite.error_log
    CustomLog   logs/application/mysite.access_log Combined
</VirtualHost>
```

videoupload.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      upload.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/videouploader/www
    ErrorLog logs/application/videoupload.error_log
    CustomLog logs/application/videoupload.access_log Combined
</VirtualHost>
```

See, we have about 50 possible something.mysite.com subdomains, all that do different things, but they're all served off the same document root.

I'd like to keep *.mysite.com in there, simply because its cleaner then having the worlds longest serveralias line, plus it protects from retards trying bananananan.mysite.com or something that wouldn't work.

I've read through the apache documentation and it didn't really have anything for this senario.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache searches for vhost matches from top to bottom and actions the firsh match that it encounters. 
If you renamed  `videoupload.conf` to  `0videoupload.conf` it would be read before `mysite.conf` and it should just work.

Comment: Not thrilled by HOW that worked, but thanks.

Comment: @GrufTech: Your other option is to put all your definitions in one file in the order you want them read.

Comment: Thats actually what I did, after I figured out apache reads top to bottom.   A single file with the subdomains above the *.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  The resolution was to remove the domain name from the headers of any other `<VirtualHost>` directive. Remove:

```
<VirtualHost test.blah.org:443>
ServerName test.blah.org
```

Replace with:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName test.blah.org
```

Using a domain name in the header caused apache to match to that virtual host in preference to my `ServerAlias static-*.blah.org` under the `<VirtualHost *:443>` directive.

Answer (score 0):

[Multiple files are included in alphabetical order.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include)

> Shell-style (fnmatch()) wildcard characters can be used in the filename or directory parts of the path to include several files at once, in alphabetical order.